# In latex/overleaf, how to compile all files at the same time?

Tags: overleaf

I am using overleaf to write my thesis, there is a *main.tex* files that includes (with the command *include*) files that are in the same directory.

When I am working on one of this sub-files, using CTRL+S does not compile the whole project, but only the current file, so I cannot see the result directly and I have to click 1st on the *main.tex* file and compile it.

So, my question is, is it possible to compile the main file from any other file ? Or to compile all at once ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried contacting the Overleaf helpdesk with your question that's highly specific to the Overleaf platform? I hear their LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: Thank you, I tested tex.se but it's a dead link...

Comment: @RandomFellow TeX.SE is an abbreviation of this site; I don't think Mico intended for you to think that is a link. You can reach Overleaf support at support@overleaf.com

Comment: using subfiles isn't often much of a help and I don't see it helps at all on overleaf: it is simpler to just have normal  `\input`.  Either way you can make every compliation use the top level file by supplying a suitable latexmkrc file to your project

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think you  are right, I sent the support a request, because I could not find how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `latexmkrc` file that runs latex on the main file whatever arguments it is given.

This seems to work in a copy of the overleaf example subfiles project

```
$pdflatex='pdflatex %O main ';
```

this shows a compilation started in the Introduction subfile but showing the full document

[image]

Currently you can view the project at

https://www.overleaf.com/read/nftpmqgyffdh

but I don't promise to keep that link forever.

Comment: cool! let me try :)

Comment: It's working! Life saving, thanks!